# How to link libraries with g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I'm trying to link a game library for my game project in C++. I am using the g++ compiler and Atom Code Editor. Also on a Windows machine.

To link the library it needs to link those things:

- Include path
- Library path
- Additional dependencies

The main.cpp file is at ProjectRoot/src/main.cpp and the library is at ProjectRoot/deps/lib_name
Inside the library there is and include folder, with the .h file for including, and a lib folder, with the .lib file. It's a static linking library.

So far, I've tried the following commands:

```
g++ -o ExecutableName.exe -I /deps/lib_name/include -L /deps/lib_name/lib src/main.cpp
```

Well, that didn't work though... It said that there was no such file or directory as library_name.h...

I need to know if I'm doing anything wrong and also how to specify the additional dependencies.

Comment: You need to link the library using `-lname_of_lib`(omit prefix lib) flag. For Eg. to link `libpthread` `-lpthread`

Comment: `pthread` is actually an exception and is linked with `-pthread` (without the 'l')

Answer (score 2):

Every thing is correct . You just forgot to link the libraries . Do it as follows -

```
g++ -o ExecutableName.exe -I /deps/lib_name/include -L /deps/lib_name/lib src/main -l[library name] -l[library name]
```